# Rails 4 - Search box that searches all keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed a tutorial on setting up a search box and got it to work on exact phrase searches. I want to make it search for results that have all keywords being searched for.

For example, a search for "Red Necklace" should return a product that is called "Red Chain Necklace" but should not return "Red Earrings".

I've looked at couple railscasts on gems like searchlogic and ransack but they seem like too much for what I'm trying to do.

```
#model code
def self.search(query)
  where("description like ? or name like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
end


#controller code
def search
    @listings = Listing.search(params[:search])
end

#view
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class:"navbar-form navbar-right") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search by color or style...", class:"form-control search-form" %>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
<% end %>
```

I read some other answers on SO that mention the `.split` method. I tried it out in a couple ways but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: For full text search you can use "solr".

Comment: thanks, is there a way to modify the model method in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose,

```
@products = Product.all
search_query = "Red Necklace"

search_query = "Red Necklace".split(" ")
```

// now the search_query becomes ["Red", "Necklace"]

Now, search those values in every product for finding the correct product.

```
result = []
@products.each do |p|
   c = 0
   search_query.each do |q|
     if p.name.include?(q)
       c +=1
     end
   end
   if c == search_query.length
     result << p
   end
end
```

Its a slow process and complexity is high.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. I'm having trouble using those search gems because I'm using windows and I'm running into installation issues. I couldn't install elastic search, which is required for most search gems. I tried  the solr gem and the ransack gem too but both had problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Full Text Search**

What you're looking for is [`full text search`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search), which is relatively difficult to achieve using standard MYSQL.

The problem you have is that the db engines are not specifically designed to be "search" engines. They are meant as a way to store & organize data. As such, the "full text" search facilities of these systems is merely based on the query interface.

I'm sure someone more experienced & knowledgeable than I can explain the specifics of this; I'll just say that in order to create the search functionalit you want, you'll want to use one of the third party search applications:

> - [Sunspot Solr](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)
> - [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)
> - [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

The difference here is that all of these recommendations *index* your data, allowing much more in-depth, efficient & specific searching. Although I've not used them specifically, I would highly recommend using one of the above.

--

**Solr**

You'll want to check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot) on how Solr works:

[image]

That's as much help I can give I'm afraid. I know you don't want this, but it's the best way for you to achieve the functionality you desire